# Need help to record a script for native apps testing using Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, test-design

When I tried to record a script for native app testing using `Jmeter` I'm facing the next issue:

when I keeping the proxy same as `Jmeter's` and IP address of my PC in android device, before changing the `proxy Wi-Fi` internet is working, but not after.

I'm unable to record scripts. Any suggestions regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all make sure you have started JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as it has to be running so your android device could access the Internet using JMeter as a proxy.
2. In case of recording secure [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) traffic you might need a third-party app like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en)
3. In case of recording HTTPS traffic you will need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate onto your device

   - locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder)
   - transfer it to your android device somehow (i.e. send it to yourself via email)
   - open the email attachment on the android device and follow system dialog to get it installed

---

An easier option would be using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-#mobile), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates. As a bonus you will be able to export recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters.